# Using Google Speech API

Tags: c#, api, speech

What is the code for implementing the Google Speech API in my C# based application? I found out that it is possible to create an audio file and sent it to http://slides.html5rocks.com/#speech-input and receive it as text. Could you please explain how to do this or provide me with the code if you have attempted this before? Been stuck here for a while now

Much appreciated.

Code So far:

```
    SpeechRecognitionEngine rec = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    SpeechSynthesizer dummy = new SpeechSynthesizer();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        Choices searching = new Choices("Porsche");
        GrammarBuilder searchService = new GrammarBuilder("Search");

        searchService.Append(searching);


        // Create a Grammar object from the GrammarBuilder and load it to the  recognizer.
        Grammar googleGrammar = new Grammar(searchService); ;
        rec.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
        rec.LoadGrammar(googleGrammar);

        // Add a handler for the speech recognized event.
        rec.SpeechRecognized +=
          new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(_recognizer_SpeechRecognized);

        // Configure the input to the speech recognizer.
        rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        // Start asynchronous, continuous speech recognition.
        rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }




    private void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            FileStream FS_Audiofile = new FileStream("temp.flac", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader BR_Audiofile = new BinaryReader(FS_Audiofile);
            byte[] BA_AudioFile = BR_Audiofile.ReadBytes((Int32)FS_Audiofile.Length);
            FS_Audiofile.Close();
            BR_Audiofile.Close();

            HttpWebRequest _HWR_SpeechToText = null;

            _HWR_SpeechToText = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=de-DE&maxresults=1&pfilter=0");

            _HWR_SpeechToText.Method = "POST";
            _HWR_SpeechToText.ContentType = "audio/x-flac; rate=44100";
            _HWR_SpeechToText.ContentLength = BA_AudioFile.Length;
            _HWR_SpeechToText.GetRequestStream().Write(BA_AudioFile, 0, BA_AudioFile.Length);

            HttpWebResponse HWR_Response = (HttpWebResponse)_HWR_SpeechToText.GetResponse();
            if (HWR_Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                StreamReader SR_Response = new StreamReader(HWR_Response.GetResponseStream());
                textBox1.Text = SR_Response.ToString();

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }  
    }
```

This does not return any value from Google.

Comment: stuck where? post your attempts and where its not working for you, SO is not a free code service, we are not here to code for you, but to help you getting your code to work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: @user3306938 you forgot to state what is wrong with your code and not working for you.

Comment: @Prix It's there below the code. basically a string value of my recording doesnt get printed

Comment: google has shut down the api url that u try to use... https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html  check the link and check the chromium source that backs the link. try following thread : http://mikepultz.com/2013/07/google-speech-api-full-duplex-php-version/

Comment: its not shut down according to the end of that last link. you may need to supply your api key and your client IP addr as stated in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following works in curl as long as the file sent is not too long... under 5 seconds.

> curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: audio/x-flac; rate=16000" \
>   -T seg_1.flac "https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize? \ xjerr=1&client=speech2text&maxresults=1&lang=en-US&key=...48593"
>
> {"status":0,"id":"","hypotheses":[{"utterance":"now it was the
>   favorite pastime","confidence":0.95148802}]}

So, encode to speechX or flac

include a parm with your sample rate from the recording

include your key

keep the file short in duration ( you will have to split files prior to API access )

Answer (score 1):

The FS_Audiofile filestream you are sending to Google is empty, that's why you are not receiving anything back.

You are missing this call:

```
recognizedAudio.WriteToAudioStream(FS_Audiofile);
```