# running Google speech locally with no external server?

Tags: android, offline, speech, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

just not to miss out, is there a way to run Google speech locally without having to go to Google server-- without even an internet connection?

[Google speech API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721436/google-speech-api), [Using Google Speech API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808192/using-google-speech-api), [Android: Speech Recognition without using google server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396046/android-speech-recognition-without-using-google-server) and several other resources say/hint "no".

this will be for voice to text. my input is the speech from the microphone, output is that speech in text.

Note: i'm aware of Sphinx among some other speech recognizers. i'll bring it up in another Q. this Q is out of interest in Google-speech for performance reasons.

TIA.

//---------------------------------------

EDIT: i'm looking for something that also runs on desktop-- Windows and not just on Android.

Comment: I believe your question is answered in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616994/offline-speech-recognition-in-android-jellybean

Comment: @GeraldSchneider i'll look up jellybean - thx for the useful link. any further info on how it can be integrated? it's 2 yrs old and is talking about a lot of issues upfront.

Answer (score 0):

The user can download an offline speech recognition package, jellybean (API 16) only. Currently at least 9% of devices are less than API 16 and therefore will not be compatible with your application. In addition to the 9% some devices do not have offline speech recognition enabled due to hardware constraints.

Please note that offline speech recognition is likely to be a battery and processor expensive feature.

Comment: does it run on Windows?

Comment: I believe there is an app GVoice.

Comment: Google voice is something else - if that's what you are referring to.